# Why my code is able to print only one node value why not other node value?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *root_1 = NULL;
struct node *root_2 = NULL;
struct node *current;

void create(int option){

    struct node *temp,*current;
    int data;

    printf("Enter data value \n");
    scanf("%d",&data);

    if(option == 1){
        if(root_1 == NULL){         
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
    //      temp->next = Null;
            current = temp; 
            root_1 = temp;
        }else{
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
            current->next = temp;  
            current = temp; 
            }           
    }else{
        if(root_2 == NULL){         
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
    //      temp->next = Null;
            current = temp; 
            root_2 = temp;
        }else{
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
            current->next = temp;  
            current = temp; 
        }           
    }
}

void dispaly(int option){

    printf("List \n");

    struct node *temp;
    if(option == 1){
        temp = root_1;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            printf("%d \n",temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }else{
        temp = root_2;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            printf("%d \n",temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

void function(int option){
        int ch;
        while(1){
            printf("1.create,2.display,3.exit \n");
            printf("Ur choice \n");
            scanf("%d",&ch);

            switch(ch){
                case 1:
                    create(option);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dispaly(option);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    exit(0);
                default:
                    printf("Wrong option \n");
            }
        }
}

void main(){
    int option;
    while(1){
        printf("1.List-1 \t 2.List-2 \n");
        printf("enter ur option \n");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option){
            case 1:
                function(option);
                break;
            case 2:
                function(option);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In my code i'm trying to create two linked lists.in this program i'm able to create two list but i'm unable to display please any can help me.two differentiate two lists i am creating two root values that are root_1 and root_2.

Comment: Can it print all the the nodes in one list?

Comment: ya i am thinking but i am not sure can you help me in this

Comment: What is the switch for?  You pass the option as a parameter, so the cases are the same.

Comment: i am passing the option value to identify whether the list is One or Two

Comment: regarding this kind of line: 'temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));' 1) don't cast the returned value from malloc (and family) 2) always check the returned value (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: I think @MartinJames is referring to the identical `switch` cases in `main()`. BTW it's a terrible idea naming a function `function`. No added value at all.

Comment: Well, what heppens if you just call option(1) in main()?  You have to debug this sotff.  Split up your problem, making it simpler.

Comment: but in my code i written condition that will success only if ( root_1 = NULL ) in this condition also when it executing first time i was storing root_1 = temp,how to possible every time it will success

Comment: In case 3, did you mean 'exit' or 'return'?

Comment: regarding this kind of line: 'scanf("%d",&ch);' 1) always check the returned value from scanf (and family) to assure the the input/conversion operations were successful.  2) left over white space needs to be consumed or skipped, so a combination of calling getchar until '\n' encountered and/or a leading ' ' (space) in the in the format string.

Comment: when i call option = 1 it will take root as root_1 else it will take root as root_2  - Martin James

Comment: What does 'unable to display' mean?  Does it segfault?  Does it loop?  What?

Comment: 0) `temp->next = Null;` --> `temp->next = NULL;` 1) `current;` is overlapped with a local name.

Comment: Use a debugger and step/breakpoint through, or add some printf() to indicate what it happening.

Comment: in case three it is not exit it is fail condition for while loop in function() when it will fail it came back to main while loop and it will ask option list-1 or list-2

Comment: @MartinJames suggest using a spell checker and proof reading before posting.  Such activity makes it much easier to read/understand code and comments

Comment: means it is printing only first value but not printing remaining other value

Comment: @- BLUEPIXY  :- those line i put in comments

Comment: regarding this line: '//      temp->next = Null;' the correct spelling is 'NULL' and all fields in a struct, especially linking fields, need to be set to the appropriate value.

Comment: But   "temp->next = Null" line i put in comments i think  this will not effect on execution....

Comment: should not be commented

Comment: thank you @BLUEPIXY i got it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// still to do:
// apply the same fix as suggested for the option == 1 code, 
// to the option == 2 code

// Note: in comparison statements, like: 'if(option == 1)',
// the literal should be on the left to enable the compiler to catch
// the following error: 
// 'if( option = 1)'  <-- single '=' rather than '=='
// I.E. use: 'if( 1 == option )'

// IMO: 'georgian' code formatting
//       removes the vertical white space 
//       that is used to greatly enhance the readability of the code
//       suggest always putting '{' and '}' on their own line

struct node *root_1 = NULL;
struct node *root_2 = NULL;
struct node *current;  // <-- remove this line (or rename the variable)
                       //      as 'current' is one of the auto variables
                       //      in the create() function

void create(int option){

    struct node *temp,*current;  
    int data;

    printf("Enter data value \n");
    scanf("%d",&data);          // <-- change to:
                                // if( 1 != scanf( " %d", &data ) )
                                // { // then scanf failed
                                //     perror( "scanf for data failed" );
                                //     // free all malloc'd areas
                                //     // for both linked lists here
                                //     exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                                //  }
                                //
                                //  // implied else, scanf successful
                                //

    if(option == 1){
        if(root_1 == NULL){         
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
    //      temp->next = Null; // <-- this line should be: 'temp->next = NULL;'
            current = temp;    // <-- remove this line, it does nothing useful
                               // attach first node to linked list
            root_1 = temp;
        }else{
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
                                // <-- insert following line to initialize link field
                                temp->next = NULL;
            current = root1;
                                // <-- insert following lines 
                                // step through linked list until end
                                while( NULL != current->next )
                                {
                                    current = current->next;
                                } // end while
                                // attach new node to end of linked list
            current->next = temp; 

            current = temp;     // <-- remove this line, 
                                // <-- it will corrupt the linked list

            }            
    }else{
        if(root_2 == NULL){         
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
    //      temp->next = Null;
            current = temp; 
            root_2 = temp;
        }else{
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->data = data;
            current->next = temp;  
            current = temp; 
        }           
    }
}
```